# Plotly not (or incorrectly) wrapping text if line break is supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm using plotly to create a table to display some data. In the third column i'd like to separate each sentence found with a new line.

[image: plotly table no line break]

If I use the `<br>` html tag to break a line it seems to mess up text wrapping:

[image: plotly table with line break]

If I instead use the `<br />` tag it seems to kind of keep the wrapping, but assumes that `<br /><br />`  and then the following text is part of same line. So then a line breaks appears in the middle of a sentence:

[image]

`<br/>` doesn't appear to do anything, and instead just inserts itself into the text.

[image]

I've also tried `\n`, but nothing happens and the `\n` doesn't display (using `\\n` displays `\\n` in place)

[image]

Below is how the table is currently being plotted:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
...
interesting_words     = remove_common_words[0:100]
interesting_sentences = []
interesting_documents = []

for index, word in enumerate(interesting_words):
    interesting_sentences.append(re.sub(r"(" + word + ")", r"<b>\1</b>", "<br><br>".join(words[word]["sentences"]), flags=re.IGNORECASE))

    # Example using <br />
    # interesting_sentences.append(re.sub(r"(" + word + ")", r"<b>\1</b>", "<br /><br />".join(words[word]["sentences"]), flags=re.IGNORECASE))

    # Example using \n
    # interesting_sentences.append(re.sub(r"(" + word + ")", r"<b>\1</b>", "\n\n".join(words[word]["sentences"]), flags=re.IGNORECASE))

    interesting_documents.append(", ".join(words[word]["documents"]))
    interesting_words[index] += f" ({words[word]['occurrences']})"

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['<b>Word (Total Occurrences)</b>', '<b>Documents</b>', '<b>Sentences containing the word</b>']),
             cells=dict(values=[interesting_words, interesting_documents, interesting_sentences]))
                 ])
fig.show()
```

How should I be correctly insert line breaks for plotly?

Comment: (Shot in the dark). Yes, generally in Plotly (as it’s rendered as HTML) `<br>` should be sufficient.  Have you tried `\n` by chance?

Comment: I have probably should of added to the examples. So I'll add it now, but it doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't even appear on the grid.